# The provided hex string is not a valid ObjectID. Mongo-go-driver

Tags: golang, mongodb, mongo

Я учу Golang. Есть 2 функции(проблема со второй):

```
func (h *Handler) getAllBooks(c *gin.Context) {
    books := h.services.Books.GetAll(c)

    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "home.page.html", gin.H{
        "books": books,
    })
    //c.JSON(http.StatusOK, books)
}

func (h *Handler) getByID(c *gin.Context) {
    bookID := c.Param("id")
    log.Println(bookID)

    id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(bookID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    book, err := h.services.Books.GetByID(c, id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "book.page.html", gin.H{
        "book": book,
    })
    //c.JSON(http.StatusOK, book)
}
```

В логах я вижу это:

```
2022/01/06 02:03:14 ObjectID("61d5d505025f7d83c5157c27")
2022/01/06 02:03:14 the provided hex string is not a valid ObjectID
2022/01/06 02:03:14 mongo: no documents in result
```

И home.page.html:

```
...
{{if .books}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Anons</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
        {{range .books}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{.Title}}</td>
            <td>{{.Anons}}</td>
            <td>{{.CreatedAt}}</td>
            <td><a href='/get/{{.ID}}'>Read Book</a></td>
        </tr>
        {{end}}
    </table>
    {{end}}
...
```

Функция primitive.IsValidObjectID() возвращает "false". Как я понял, когда мы парсим ID со строки поиска(c.Param("id")), то мы получаем ID уже в правильном формате, но с типом String. Возможно лучше будет создать еще одно поле ID в MongoDB, но уже с типом String? Как это можно исправить более правильно, так сказать?

PS* функция "h.services.Books.GetByID(c, id)" ожидает "id" с типом primitive.ObjectID. И в шаблонизатор мы передаем {{.ID}} с типом primitive.ObjectID

Comment: из параметра приходит `ObjectID("61d5d505025f7d83c5157c27")`. а должно быть просто hex `"61d5d505025f7d83c5157c27"`. тогда функция `primitive.ObjectIDFromHex` отработает нормально

Comment: Да, я понимаю это, но как это правильно исправить можно? Я думаю создавать функцию, которая будет обрезать "ObjectID( .... ) " , не очень правильно. Хотелось бы как-то более красиво это решить

Comment: я это решил тем, что добавил в _id (просто UUID) в колекцию и избавился от ObjectID. и все запросы приходили с UUID. и этот _id будет PK для твоей коллекции

Comment: Тоже так думал сделать, но удивился, что в инете есть много проектов golang + mongo, и там как-то используют нормально ObjectID. Возможно gin просто парсит как-то не так id

Comment: тут проблема не в джине. а в том, что в результате`bookID := c.Param("id")` получается `bookID == "ObjectID("61d5d505025f7d83c5157c27")"`, и тут проблема в том, что с той стороны прислали не то, что вам надо. можете договориться с клиентом, чтобы прислал только hex. 
но также вы передаете "голый" объект клиенту `"book": book`. вы можете исходный book поменять так, чтобы ID был hex-ом,  а не строкой  ObjectID("61d5d505025f7d83c5157c27")

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Не мог бы, пожалуйста, скинуть ссылку на репозиторий, или кратко сказать, как ты сохранял в бд id с типом uuid.UUID?

Comment: завтра отвечу, если не забуду

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Просто напомню *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предположим вы реализуете ручку для работы с юзерами.

на вход в ручку приходит JSON. нам нужно его распарсить, сохранить в базе и выдать обратно.

```
// User, который приходит к нам.
type User struct {
    ID            string            `json:"id"`
    Email         string            `json:"e-mail"`
    FirstName     string            `json:"first_name"`
    LastName      string            `json:"last_name"`
}

// ручка для создания юзера
func CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   usr := User{}
   err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&usr)
   if err != nil {
    panic(err) // так не делай
   }
 
   // тут можно сгенерировать новый ID если нужно
   usr.ID = uuid.New().String()


   err = u.storage.SetUser(r.Context(), usr)
   if err != nil {
    panic(err) // так не делай
   }

....

}
```

теперь нам надо как-то сохранять или обновлять нашего пользователя.

```
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type userDTO struct {
    ID               string    `bson:"_id"`
    Email            string    `bson:"email"`
    FirstName        string    `bson:"first_name"`
    LastName         string    `bson:"last_name"`
}
// `bson:"_id"` -- _id значит, что это ключ в монго. 



// это будет абстракцией исходны данных от тех, что хотим сохранить в базе.  
// То есть модель нашей базы
func toUserDTO(u User) userDTO {
    return userDTO{
        ID:            u.ID,
        Email:         u.Email,
        FirstName:     u.FirstName,
        LastName:      u.LastName
    }
}

type DB struct {
    datasource *mongo.Database
}

func (d *DB) SetUser(ctx context.Context, usr users.User) error {
    upsert := true

    _, err := d.datasource.Collection(usersCollection).
        UpdateOne(
            ctx,
            bson.M{"_id": usr.ID}, // вот тут и укажем уникальный ключ. это синтаксис монго
            bson.M{"$set": toUserDTO(usr)}, // вставить или обновить 
            &options.UpdateOptions{
                Upsert: &upsert,
            },
        )
    if err != nil {
        dbexp, ok := err.(mongo.WriteException)
        if !ok {
            return fmt.Errorf("couldn't update user in the DB: %w", err)
        }

        for _, r := range dbexp.WriteErrors {
            if r.Code == 11000 {
                return fmt.Errorf("couldn't update user in the DB: %w", users.ErrNotUniqueEntity)
            }
        }

        return fmt.Errorf("couldn't update user in the DB: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}


func toModel(u userDTO) User {
    return users.User{
        ID:        u.ID,
        Email:     u.Email,
        FirstName: u.FirstName,
        LastName:  u.LastName
    }
}


// ну а это будет выборка юзеров по ID
func (d *DB) Users(ctx context.Context, id []string) ([]User, error) {
    query := bson.M{}

    if len(id) != 0 {
        query["_id"] = bson.M{"$in": id}
    }

    cur, err := d.datasource.Collection(usersCollection).
        Find(
            ctx,
            query,
        )

    if errors.Is(err, mongo.ErrNoDocuments) {
        return nil, nil
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("couldn't query users: %w", err)
    }

    if cur.Err() != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("couldn't query users: %w", cur.Err())
    }

    dtos := []userDTO{}

    err = cur.All(ctx, &dtos)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("couldn't decode users: %w", err)
    }

    models := make([]User, 0, len(dtos))
    for _, d := range dtos {
        models = append(models, toModel(d))
    }

    return models, nil
}
```

[подробнее про первичный ключ в монго][1]

> The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value
> must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type
> other than an array. If the _id contains subfields, the subfield names
> cannot begin with a ($) symbol.

использовал зависимость `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.3.3`
[1]: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/